# Latex commands giving weird symbols

Tags: symbols, subscripts

```
\begin{align*}
(\Delta\otimes id)\cal{R}=\cal{R}_{13}\cal{R}_{23}, 
(id\otimes \Delta)\cal{R}=\cal{R}_{13}\cal{R}_{12},\\
\tau\circ \Delta h=\cal{R}(\Delta h)\cal{R}^{-1}, \forall h \in H
\end{align*}
```

The above LaTeX code is giving me weird symbols in the subscripts but I'm not sure why.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The syntax `\cal{R}` has been wrong from day one of LaTeX.

In the olden days, the correct way to get a calligraphic “R” was

```
{\cal R}
```

but about 30 years ago the new syntax

```
\mathcal{R}
```

was proposed and the old one deprecated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\swapnumbers
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\newcommand{\cR}{\mathcal{R}}
\newcommand{\cH}{\mathcal{H}}
\newcommand{\id}{\mathit{id}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
A quasitriangular Hopf algebra is a pair $(H,\cR)$ where $H$
is a Hopf algebra and $\cR\in\cH\otimes\cH$ and obeys
\begin{gather*}
(\Delta\otimes \id)\cR=\cR_{13}\cR_{23}, \quad
(\id\otimes \Delta)\cR=\cR_{13}\cR_{12},\\
\tau\circ \Delta h=\cR(\Delta h)\cR^{-1}, \forall h \in H
\end{gather*}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did think I was calling mathcal with cal; 
\providecommand{\cal}{\mathcal}  

I've replaced cal with mathcal and it's worked.

Comment: @Inspectorgadget `\providecommand` does nothing if the command is already defined and `\cal` is for backward compatibility.